# syncing android gradle appcompat 27.0.1

Tags: android, android-studio

I am new to android studio and not sure about gradle settings. I have downloaded Android API 27.

this is error I get:

> Error:Unable to resolve dependency for ':app@debug/compileClasspath':
>   Could not resolve com.android.support:appcompat-v7:27.0.1.

this is build.gradle (project):

```
all sub-projects/modules.
    buildscript {
        repositories {
            jcenter()
            google()
        }
        dependencies {
            classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.0.1'
        }
    }

    allprojects {
        repositories {
            jcenter()
            google()
        }
    }
```

and this is build.gradle (Module app)

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

def var = android {
    compileSdkVersion 27
    buildToolsVersion "27.0.1"

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.sample.sample"
        minSdkVersion 13
        targetSdkVersion 26
    }

    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.txt'
        }
    }
}
var

dependencies {
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:27.0.1'
}
```

and this is available SDK tools I use:
[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Delete .gradle file in project section. thn clean project-reuild-run.

Comment: After Celaning project I get this new error:
Error:(1, 0) Plugin with id 'com.android.application' not found.

Comment: try to disable instant run in setting->build

Comment: Thank you. The main question was answered. I am working on instant run. Its grayed out and I can not disable it