# Unable to mergedex after updating to android studio 3.0

Tags: android, android-manifest, dex, android-studio-3.0

After Updating my Studio to 3.0, I encountered with the issue:

```
Error:Execution failed for task ':app:processDebugManifest'. 
> Manifest merger failed : Attribute meta-data#android.support.VERSION@value value=(26.0.0) from [com.android.support:design:26.0.0] 
AndroidManifest.xml:28:13-35 is also present at [com.android.support:appcompat-v7:26.1.0] AndroidManifest.xml:28:13-35 value=(26.1.0). 
Suggestion: add 'tools:replace="android:value"' to <meta-data> element at AndroidManifest.xml:26:9-28:38 to override.
```

I solved that issue by adding the following code:

```
configurations.all {
resolutionStrategy.eachDependency { DependencyResolveDetails details ->
    def requested = details.requested
    if (requested.group == 'com.android.support') {
        if (!requested.name.startsWith("multidex")) {
            details.useVersion '26.0.2'
        }
    }
}
```

}

but after introducing that code at the end of my build.gradle, it displays another error when I try to run my application on my phone :

```
Error:Execution failed for task ':app:transformDexArchiveWithExternalLibsDexMergerForDebug'.
> java.lang.RuntimeException: com.android.builder.dexing.DexArchiveMergerException: Unable to merge dex
```

> I referred to many links with the similar problems, but I couldn't find the solution to my problem.

This is my build.gradle (Module:app)

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
compileSdkVersion 26
buildToolsVersion '26.0.2'
defaultConfig {
    multiDexEnabled true
    applicationId "com.example.mahe.blooddonation"
    minSdkVersion 19
    targetSdkVersion 26
    versionCode 1
    versionName "1.0"
    testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    vectorDrawables.useSupportLibrary = true
}


buildTypes {
    release {
        minifyEnabled false

        proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
    }
}

}
dependencies {
compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
androidTestCompile('com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:2.2.2', {
    exclude group: 'com.android.support', module: 'support-annotations'
})

implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
//noinspection GradleCompatible
implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:26.1.0'
implementation 'com.android.support:support-v4:26.1.0'
implementation 'com.android.support:design:26.1.0'
implementation 'com.android.support:cardview-v7:26.1.0'
implementation 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.0.2'
implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:11.6.2'
implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-auth:11.6.2'
testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test:runner:1.0.1'
androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.0.1'


compile 'com.mcxiaoke.volley:library-aar:1.0.0'
compile files('libs/activation.jar')
compile files('libs/additionnal.jar')
compile files('libs/google-play-services.jar')
compile files('libs/http-core-4.1.jar')
compile files('libs/httpclient-4.0.3.jar')
compile files('libs/mail.jar')  }
```

My build.gradle for the Project is:

```
// Top-level build file where you can add configuration options common to all sub-projects/modules.

buildscript {
repositories {
    jcenter()
    google()
}
dependencies {
    classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.0.1'
    classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:3.0.0'
}
}

allprojects {
repositories {
    maven{
        url "https://github.com/omadahealth/omada-nexus/raw/master/release"
    }
    jcenter()
    google()
}   
}
task clean(type: Delete) {
delete rootProject.buildDir
}
```

My Manifest File is:

```
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
package="com.example.mahe.blooddonation">

<!--
     The ACCESS_COARSE/FINE_LOCATION permissions are not required to use
     Google Maps Android API v2, but you must specify either coarse or fine
     location permissions for the 'MyLocation' functionality. 
-->
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
<uses-permission android:name="com.google.android.providers.gsf.permission.READ_GSERVICES" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE" />

<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@mipmap/dexter"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
    android:supportsRtl="true"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
    <activity android:name=".IntroScreen">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
    <activity android:name=".SignUp" />
    <activity android:name=".Login" />
    <activity
        android:name=".DonorOrReciever"
        android:label="@string/title_activity_donor_or_reciever" />
    <activity android:name=".RecieverActivity" />
    <activity android:name=".ActivityProfile" />
    <activity android:name=".EditProfile"></activity>
</application>
```

And I have removed the configurations block  of code from my gradle, and it compiles  fine without it, but still, I encounter with unable to merge dex.

my complete Stack Trace:

```
Error:java.lang.RuntimeException: java.lang.RuntimeException: java.lang.RuntimeException: com.android.builder.dexing.DexArchiveMergerException: Unable to merge dex

Error:java.lang.RuntimeException: java.lang.RuntimeException: com.android.builder.dexing.DexArchiveMergerException: Unable to merge dex

Error:java.lang.RuntimeException: com.android.builder.dexing.DexArchiveMergerException: Unable to merge dex

Error:com.android.builder.dexing.DexArchiveMergerException: Unable to merge dex

Error:com.android.dex.DexIndexOverflowException: method ID not in [0, 0xffff]: 65536
```

I Hope someone could be helpful to me.

Comment: Try this solution and check comments also https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47607765/syncing-android-gradle-appcompat-27-0-1/47607794?noredirect=1#comment82175181_47607794

Comment: compile 'com.android.support:multidex:1.0.1' try this line in your app level gradle file and replace 'compile' with 'implementation'

Comment: including the 'implementation' line didn't work out @mudit_sen I still have that unable to merge dex coming up.

Comment: @venkateshkumar you have replied to delete .gradle  file. The '.gradle' file at the C://Users//SystemName location, or the '.gradle' file  that comes on creating the project?

Answer (score 0):

I tried with an empty project and the following `build.gradle`

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 26
    buildToolsVersion '26.0.2'

    defaultConfig {
        multiDexEnabled true
        applicationId "bla.bla.bla"
        minSdkVersion 21
        targetSdkVersion 26
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
        vectorDrawables.useSupportLibrary = true
    }

    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    //noinspection GradleCompatible
    implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:26.1.0'
    implementation 'com.android.support:support-v4:26.1.0'
    implementation 'com.android.support:design:26.1.0'
    implementation 'com.android.support:cardview-v7:26.1.0'
    implementation 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.0.2'
    implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:11.6.2'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-auth:11.6.2'
    implementation 'com.mcxiaoke.volley:library-aar:1.0.0'
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test:runner:1.0.1'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.0.1'
    androidTestCompile('com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:2.2.2', {
        exclude group: 'com.android.support', module: 'support-annotations'
    })
}
```

... and everything works for me. Maybe try the same and add your local libs one after the other to see what is causing this error. I hope you find the problem like this.

Comment: I tried the same method, by introducing all the requirements you corrected, but I still encounter myself with this unable to merge dex while running my app

Comment: @MaheshwarArulraj could you maybe display the full stack trace in your question so we can check for other possible solutions?

Comment: I have mentioned my full stack trace in the question.. those two lines of runtime exception is all that comes on the stacktrace, when I run my app @Peppermint Paddy

Comment: @MaheshwarArulraj can you try to use everywhere in your gradle file where it says `com.android.support` the same version number in your case `26.0.2` and then do a `Rebuild Project`? Otherwise I'm a bit clueless, will delete my answer afterwards.

Comment: I used the same version number, but I still have the problem coming up, and It also pops me with a warning to update the version  to `26.1.0`

Comment: @MaheshwarArulraj why do you use so many play-services? The location one should be in the whole package and what is the `google-play-services.jar`? Can you get rid of some and update these to `11.6.2`? I also think after aligning the version numbers you can get rid of your first fix with `configurations.all {..}`

Comment: I have updated the gradle. Please look into it, help me out. @PeppermintPaddy

Comment: Thanks for the solution. I have been using Web Services for the past 2 days, and I had no problem. But when I tried introducing Firebase authentication int my app, the problems start to show up as mentioned above