# Gradle sync failed || Android Studio

Tags: android, android-studio, gradle

I get the error message Gradle sync failed. I already searched for solutions on stackoverflow and found similar problems but the solution there could not solve my problem:
Example-->

*[syncing android gradle appcompat 27.0.1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47607765/syncing-android-gradle-appcompat-27-0-1)*

build Gradle//Project is like this-->:

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
        maven { url "http://jcenter.bintray.com"}
    }

    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:2.3.3'
        classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:3.1.0'

    }
}
allprojects {
    repositories {
        mavenCentral()
        jcenter{ url "http://jcenter.bintray.com/" }
        maven {
            //url "https://jitpack.io"
            url "https://maven.google.com" // Google's Maven repository
        }

    }
}
task clean(type: Delete) {
    delete rootProject.buildDir
}
```

and the build gradle module is like this-->:

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
android {
    compileSdkVersion 27
    buildToolsVersion '27.0.3'
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "hibo.testxml"
        minSdkVersion 19
        targetSdkVersion 25
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}
dependencies {
    compile fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
    androidTestCompile('com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:2.2.2', {
        exclude group: 'com.android.support', module: 'support-annotations'
    })

    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:27.0.3'
    compile 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.0.0-alpha7'
    compile 'com.android.support:design:27.3.1'
    // FireBase
    compile 'com.firebase:firebase-client-android:2.3.1'
    compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging:11.8.0'
    compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-core:11.8.0'

    testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'

}//Add this line
apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
```

I hope somone can help me solve this problem.

ps:thanks in advance :D

Comment: Please add your logs too in the question. Otherwise its difficult to answer what is the problem?

Comment: where are the logs

Comment: you should have to use 27.0.2 and try again

Comment: no did not work -->  Gradle sync failed: Failed to find Build Tools revision 27.0.2
   Consult IDE log for more details

Answer (score 0):

By The way your problem is that you are using different versions for build tools and in dependencies.

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
android {
    compileSdkVersion 27
    buildToolsVersion '27.0.3'
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "hibo.test"
        minSdkVersion 19
        targetSdkVersion 25
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}
dependencies {
    compile fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
    androidTestCompile('com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:2.2.2', {
        exclude group: 'com.android.support', module: 'support-annotations'
    })

    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:27.0.3'
    compile 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.0.0-alpha7'
    compile 'com.android.support:design:25.3.1'
    // FireBase
    compile 'com.firebase:firebase-client-android:2.3.1'
    compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging:11.8.0'
    compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-core:11.8.0'

    testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'

}//Add this line
apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
```

Now use this in your gradle. May be you have not 27.0.3 install. Then an error will come in gradle Console. Then install these tools by clicking the error.

Comment: hi I did as you suggested but still i get the same error Gradle sync failed I also invalidate and restart the project, and I also did not get any error message in the gradle console.

Comment: First of all you should show us your logs. Unless the problem can't be addressed.

Comment: for what do you need the logs if I would put the logs here there would be 1000 lines of comments. Or do you mean the Event Logs.